how to share a model defined in one database in other databases
I am being asked to implement something that I just can't wrap my head around. Basically, there are two repo and projects. In ProjectA, we have collection User.
Then in second project sitting its own repository, I need to use User model from ProjectA. I exported it and imported in ProjectB but it ends up creating User model again in ProjectB.
I feel it is impossible and gave up.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use the same Scheme for both projects.
you have 2 options really

Actually use the same DB for 2 different projects (which seems unreasonable why you would want to do that)

Just copy your Scheme into your new project and create a new model. this is fine


Additional Thoughts (regarding the second option):

Consistency: If the schema for User changes in ProjectA, you'll need to manually update it in ProjectB to keep them
consistent.

Maintenance: Having the same schema in two places means you have to maintain both, which can increase the chance of errors or
inconsistencies over time.

Shared Library: Another approach could be to create a shared library or module that contains the schema/models. Both projects can
then import this shared library. This way, you have a single source
of truth for your models and schemas, which can help with
consistency and maintenance. However, this requires both projects to
be able to access and use this shared library.



thanks @KLTR. I just played around with option 3 earlier on but both projects create the same collection. Both projects create their own databases...I guess that's the main issue

If you want to use the same database just use the same connection string… what is the problem?

oh was TOLD not to use the database; no explanation given.

A repo is just somewhere to store your code. It is independent from your database.
If you want to use the User model from ProjectA across more than one project, for example in ProjectB then you can. In fact, that is one of the core principles of code reuse with Node.js. The ability to export a module and then import that module somewhere else is what the ECMAScript modules were designed for.
You probably just need to identify that in each project your connection URI is what determines which database/collection should be used by the Project.
ProjectA:
// app.js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { User } from "./models/User.js";

const app = express();
const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/projecta" //< projecta

mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => {
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
}).catch(err => {
   console.log('Error connecting:', err)
})

//... rest of your project

ProjectB:
// app.js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { User } from "./models/User.js";

const app = express();
const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/projectb" //< projectb

mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => {
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
}).catch(err => {
   console.log('Error connecting:', err)
})

//... rest of your project

Above you can see the only difference in both projects is that the connection uri is different. ProjectA connects to the projecta database and ProjectB connects to the projectb database. These can exist on the same MongoDB instance.
The connection is what mongoose uses to make database CRUD operations. You can even have multiple connections within the same project all connecting to different databases with mongoose.createConnection().

thanks. So we have User model in both databases with this approach yeah?

Yes that's correct. You have one Model which maps to a collection. That collection can be in two databases. The uri is what determines which database the collection will be created. A User model is a common model to create so using it multiple projects is quite normal. @NieSelam
